# How can I tree a folder in batch without listing the current directory?

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to use the tree command to list a file system but it adds extra information such as current directory and what directory is being listed.

I have tried looking into the tree attributes but cant seem to find anything that works.

```
rem Asks for user input
set /p COMMAND=What would you like to do? : 
rem Locates the command specified by the user
goto %COMMAND%

:settings
echo.
rem Clarifies that the action has been completed
echo Successfully opened settings panel
echo.
rem Shows a graphical tree of the specified file structure
tree "%CD%\settings\"
pause
```

I am only expecting:

```
├───accounts
├───apps
├───devices
├───language
├───network
├───personalization
├───privacy
├───security
├───system
├───time
└───update
```

But instead I get:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000C2A7 06D5:17B1
C:\USERS\NOAH HERRON\DESKTOP\SYSTEM MANAGEMENT\SETTINGS
├───accounts
├───apps
├───devices
├───language
├───network
├───personalization
├───privacy
├───security
├───system
├───time
└───update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header is build into the executable `tree.com`
(yes despite being a 64bit program it is named `.com`)

Use a for /f to parse the output and skip 3 lines:

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%A in ('tree "%CD%\settings\"') do Echo:%%A
```

or simply pipe tree output to `|more +3`

```
tree "%CD%\settings\" | more +3
```